# PHP curl data fetching from LinkedIn blocked in production server

Tags: javascript, php, curl, linkedin-api

I am fetching data such as Name, Job and Company Name from LinkedIn public profile URL's using CURL.
The code I use is shown below:

```
$ch = curl_init($linkedin_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$content = curl_exec($ch) or die ("Couldn't connect to $linkedin_url.");
```

In production server, it was working perfectly for more than a week. But now it unable to fetch the data.
It seems like LinkedIn has blocked the Production server IP due to continuous access to public profile URL's.

It works fine in Dev server and Local server.

The below is the CURL response in production server:

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
  var domain = document.domain;
  var newDomainIndex = 0;
  if (domain.substr(0, 6) == "touch.") {
    newDomainIndex = 6;
  }
  else if (domain.substr(0, 7) == "tablet.") {
    newDomainIndex = 7;
  }
  if (newDomainIndex) {
    domain = domain.substr(newDomainIndex);
  }
  window.location = "https://" + domain +  "/uas/login?trk=sentinel_org_block&session_redirect=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location);
}
</script>
</head></html>
```

Is there any workaround for this issue?

I am aware of LinkedIn Javascript API but it may be changed by them in future which might create further issues in the same thing.

Can any one please help me with a good suggestion or work around for this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the APIs they provide, that’s what they are for.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I used LinkedIn oauth API and its working fine now.